# I am losing my api data when I refresh my react app

Tags: reactjs

I am using axios to fetch and retrieve data from an api. I then set the api data to some state. When I save the changes, it shows the name from index [0] of the array, as I want. However when I refresh the page, it throws an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')". It seems like I am losing the api data when I refresh, what am I doing wrong here? The api endpoint is madeup, as I don't want to share the real endpoint here.

```
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://some-api")
      .then((res) => {
        setApiData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
  }, []);

return <h1>{apiData[0].name}</h1>
```

Comment: Effects happen after the first render. You should check for apiData before using it. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects

Answer (score 1):

try it please

> `return <h1>{ aapiData.length && apiData[0]?.name}</h1>`

Comment: that worked, can you explain?

Comment: if aapiData has any data it is working acording to me.
apiData[0]?.name also this code controls apiData[0]? first object and name

Comment: The snippet given checks the `length` of the `apiData` array. If the array has any elements, the length would be greater than `0`, which is a truthy value and then it would try to access the `name` property of the first element in the array. This guarantees that the array has at least one element before trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with refreshing the page.  This will *always* happen on the first render for this component.

The initial state value is an empty array:

```
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
```

And you're trying to access the first element of that array:

```
return <h1>{apiData[0].name}</h1>
```

An empty array has no first element, so it throws an error.

You can use optional chaining:

```
return <h1>{apiData[0]?.name}</h1>
```

Or perhaps check if it's there before using it:

```
return <h1>{apiData[0] && apiData[0].name}</h1>
```

Or not render anything at all if the array is empty:

```
return apiData.length > 0 ? <h1>{apiData[0].name}</h1> : null;
```